# Player pays too much for houses in Monopoly?

Tags: monopoly, ethics

In a two player game of Monopoly a player pays $100 per house where he should’ve paid $50 per house. 30 minutes later, the player puts houses on the property again.

The other player noticed that the first player has paid too much and says those houses are only $50. The first player then wants a refund for his previous purchase.

Should that player be entitled to a refund?

Comment: Not an answer I can back up with rules but...   It's just a game.  a mistake was made,  let them have their money back and move on!    By the rules he probably isn't entitled but do you want gaming to be fun and them want to play games with you again?

Comment: Without an official rule to say either way, this cannot be answered except with an opinion on which is better, being harsh or being generous.

Comment: @Nij While we won't have an official answer it is still possible to have a generic answer on how to handle mistakes like this in games in general.

Answer (score 7):

This question is not about Monopoly, but about gaming ethics.

- If this happens in an official tournament, then a referee will probably not allow a refund.
- If this happens in a friendly game, better to be friendly and allow it.  The goal is that everybody will have fun. A win due to someone doing a silly mistake is a silly win.

Comment: Isn’t there a limit of how long you can wait to correct the mistake? Such as waiting to correct it until doing so would prevent you from losing?

Comment: What rule places that limit? And if it would prevent you losing now, it's almost sure that doing it correctly earlier would have even greater impact to prevent losing as well.

Comment: @Nij The rules can't cover every situation and there are good reasons to have a limit in place for how long a mistake can be fixed because it can negatively impact the game if it happens a long time after the mistake.

Comment: The rules do place a limit on how long you can recover rent after the fact. But not on correcting other errors. It would have been easy to make this limit more general, but it is not.

Comment: @Nij The fact that the rules do limit how long you can correct some mistakes also suggest that there is a general limit on how long you have to correct mistakes in general.

Comment: It doesn't suggest that at all: the rule makers chose to put a limit on that specific action and chose to not put a limit on any other. There simply is no limit.

Comment: @Nij Although the incentives to delay correct payment to prevent losing may only arise in fairly narrow situations, the impact on the outcome of the game when it does happen would likely be huge.  If Player A is not successfully bankrupted by Player B when they otherwise would have been, and A is later bankrupted by Player C instead, then C gains a massive advantage relative to B.

Comment: More broadly, IMO the answer to pretty much every "gaming ethics" question of this nature is to communicate in advance when your casual play group wishes to deviate from a known tournament rule.  If an issue arises mid-game, then use tournament rules and communicate the deviation before the next game, unless everyone agrees otherwise, but "majority rule" deviations should be communicated in advance.

Comment: There is just too much variation in each player's mental representation of a game to assume implicit consensus around what "should" happen in a given circumstance.  Policy is, at the least, a Schelling Point around which a temporary consensus can be justified.

Comment: Arguing that you can't fix a mistake because it would change the course of the game is a pretty weak point. The mistake itself has already changed the course of the game directly. Bringing up "tournament rules" as if everyone knows they exist, let alone knows and uses them, in a casual environment, is a red herring. You can't deviate from rules that never applied in the first place! Again, as this answer has said, it's purely down to what the group decides, which should be for the most fun.

Comment: @Nij A proposed fix changing the course of a game isn't intrinsically problematic, sure, but in this case it leads either to unwieldy tracking obligations or incentive incompatibility in Nash Equilibrium gameplay. That is, you're forced to decide either that players are allowed to intentionally overpay as a strategy (which requires maintaining consensus on the entire history of the game's financial transactions to function), or that they are not (which opens the door to a player drastically altering the course of a game by lying about their intentions).  Both seem worth avoiding, if feasible.

Comment: The idea behind respecting a tournament rule (assuming the players do indeed know the rule) even though it does not apply in casual settings, is that it may be the most reasonable Schelling Point available.  Players overestimate the extent to which their mental representations of a game naturally overlap, and thus tend to believe everyone shares their intuitions on how nuances should be resolved.  There's nothing wrong with deciding to use some alternative non-tournament rule, but IMO this should always be communicated in advance, not after a player has already pursued a strategy in question.

Comment: The entire point of this problem is that **no** rules have been agreed, beyond those on the paper with the game itself. Tournament rules are very much not part of the package, so to speak of agreeing on an alternative is misleading; the tournament rules themselves are an alternative to the true default resolution which is "no rule exists"!

Comment: @Nij Right, that's exactly what a Schelling Point achieves.  It establishes a default for consensus when no rule exists and players can't communicate.  In this case, it's not that the players literally can't communicate, but that they can't communicate behind a veil of ignorance regarding the game state, as they could have before the game began.

Answer (score 0):

No, because the mistake was made too long ago to be retconned. While the rules don't say anything about overpaying for a house they also don't say anything about getting money back when overpaying the bank. In cases like this it is generally a good idea to limit how far back a mistake can be undone which is generally a turn or two later. In this case the mistake was noted 30 minutes later which means a lot of game play has happened and the time for fixing the mistake is over.

If the mistake had been noted more promptly such as in the next turn or two a refund should be given as long as it will not negatively impact the game based on what has happened since the mistake.

As a note this is a general rule to making mistakes in games and how they should be fixed and doesn't just apply to this situation.

Answer (score -2):

No. He is not entitled to a refund, as he made the mistake and already paid the money, thus altering the dynamic of the game. (Even if it hurt him more than you.)

Disclaimer: Despite this, there is nowhere in the official rules where it states a passage about refunds, it is generally assumed that when a player makes a mistake (and it hurts his position) and the game proceeds, the mistake is accepted and not reversed as it would affect the latter positions of players in the game.

However, if y'all are playing with house rules, it is plausible to allow him to get a refund if you both agree. This would be a mutual decision however, and not in accordance with the rules of the game.

Comment: Do the rules say that you can overpay for houses? If they don't, then you've entered an illegal game state.  Does monopoly have rules for resolving an illegal game state?

Comment: Mistakes in games should be fixed when possible though in this case as it was noticed 30 minutes later I think it is no longer possible to fix.